# Read more button with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a full the content. When I click on the button, immediately all the blocks are shown completely, but I need to completely show only the block that I clicked on
php

```
 <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
           <div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
           <button class="show-more">Show more</button>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

css

```
.content { max-height: 20px; overflow: hidden; }
.show-more { margin-top: 15px; }
```

jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.show-more').click(function() {
    jQuery('.content').css('max-height', 'none');
    jQuery(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you target `.content` you are selecting all elements in that class. You may switch to ID selector or using .prev() to select only the previous element:

```
jQuery(this).prev(".content").css('max-height', 'none');
```

You should also remove `overflow:hidden`:

```
jQuery(this).prev(".content").css({'max-height':'none','overflow':'auto'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the closest `.content`

Try this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.show-more').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.content').css({'max-height':'none','overflow':'auto'});
    jQuery(this).remove();
  });
});
``
```

Comment: this code work , but it close, but i want open .content

Comment: Set the overflow also? Does this change work? I have updated the answer